# Mod Rewrite Rule redirects

Tags: mod-rewrite

I was trying to password protect a folder on our server. However, each time I included .htaccess to that folder, and .htpasswd, it was automatically redirecting everyone to a 401 page without any login prompt. 
When i visited my root directly, i saw this .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
#RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I commented it out and my .htpasswd & .htaccess to the foldr works, however, as my mod rewrite isn't the best, I wasn't sure if commenting the above will create problems for my website?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically just redirecting any www.host.ext to host.ext, and returns a 301 Moved Permanently response code.

If you don't care about that functionality you should be able to comment it out.

post your subdirectories htaccess file and we can see if we can sort your original issue out.